# output text not displying the account lookup corresponding contact

Tags: apex

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="case_obj__c" extensions="caseobj">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:inputField value="{!a.Account__c}"/><br/>
   <apex:outputtext value="{!c.name}" label="dis"/><br/>
   <apex:commandLink action="{!save}" value="ok"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
Public class caseobj{

 public case_obj__c a {get;set;}
 public  contact c {get;set;}

 public caseobj(apexPages.standardController con){
  this.a = (case_obj__c)con.getRecord();
}

 public void save(){
  id b =(id)a.Account__c;
  contact c=[select name from contact where accountID=:b];
  system.debug(c);
 }

}
```

if i select account in the lookup field it should automatically show the corresponding contact in the output text field.but it is not displaying help me out

Comment: you probably want to re-render your page ?

Comment: You aren't really telling it to do that anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use rerender attribute in  to show the contacts when you click Save. Also as there can be more than one contact under each account, it is better to assign the contact query list to a list of contacts. Please find updated code below,

```
<apex:page standardController="case_obj__c" extensions="caseobj">
<apex:form >
  <apex:inputField value="{!a.Account__c}"/><br/>
  <apex:outputpanel id="contacts">
   <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="c">
    <apex:outputtext value="{!c.name}" label="dis"/><br/>
   </apex:repeat>
  </apex:outputpanel>
   <apex:commandLink action="{!save}" rerender="contacts" value="ok"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller code updated to show more than one contact

```
Public class caseobj{

 public case_obj__c a {get;set;}
 public  List<contact> contactList {get;set;}

 public caseobj(apexPages.standardController con){
  this.a = (case_obj__c)con.getRecord();
 }

 public void save(){
  id b =(id)a.Account__c;
  contactList =[select name from contact where accountID=:b];
  system.debug(contactList);
 }

}
```